# dynamically linked rust binary with musl library

Tags: rust, embedded-linux, musl

I have a rust program, would like to link with musl-libc library because I would like to keep the run time memory foot print small. I can link musl and build a static binary easily. But I would like to create a dynamically linked binary with musl library. Is there any way to do this?